# Add observablearray index value to observablearray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, ko.observablearray

I have an observable array containing mapped Json data. The data is already sorted by 'Performance'.

What I need to do is add a ranking to the array so my `foreach` renders the numbered rank. So far, I've been using $index which works fine until I use sorting and paging extenders that change the array index. Am I right in thinking the best approach would be to add each index value to the array?

Something tells me this should be quite simple but I've yet to discover the right approach.

```
viewModel.integerlists = ko.observableArray([]);

function IntegerLists(data) {
    this.IntegerListID = data.IntegerListID;
    this.Performance = data.Performance;
    this.Direction = data.Direction;
    this.Integers = ko.observableArray(data.Integers);
}

$.getJSON("/Home/GetIntegerLists", function (allData) {
    var mappedIntegers = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new IntegerLists(item) });
    viewModel.integerlists(mappedIntegers);
});
```

Comment: I have had good luck with an `indexed` extension that subscribes to the observableArray and takes one pass through updating an index on each one.  The second part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229578/knockoutjs-access-index-of-item-in-array-from-within-the-javascript-template/12230148#12230148

Comment: Thanks RP - that's interesting but doesn't really solve my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/zGmcg/26/ If you click the 'score' link, the scoring order is toggled but the index remains the same, as it should. I don't necessarily need the index, I just need a way to rank array members based on score.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pagination then simple solution would be to remember which page you are on and just show (page-1)*(number_of_items_per_page) + $index.

If you use filtering, then there is nothing you can do on client side because you wouldn't get back items that are filtered out, unless you keep all data on client and then filter them out which is, in my opinion, bad. In case you go to server for data, all I can see doing is get all items from database ordered by performance, then you use extended class:

```
public class ExtendedMyClass
{
  public MyClass theObject{get;set;}
  public int rank{get;set;}
}
```

and return it like that. This way, your server will have most recent and most accurate data, process it pretty fast and return to you only what you need. Of course, after adding rank, you should process how you filtered data - which page you want and which filters you applied.

On the other hand, if you have ALL data on client, you can simply iterate through it and dynamically add rank. You wrote they are sorted so following code should do:

```
var counter = 1;
mappedIntegers.forEach(function (singleInteger){
  singleInteger.rank = counter;
  counter++;
});
```